# sql with an array

Tags: sql

Can this loop be done in sql ?

```
Dim ID(0 TO 2) as string
Dim number as string

ID="01"
ID="02"


For each number in ID
   SELECT data FROM sheet1 WHERE data= number
next number

datatable:
data
01
01
02
03
04
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using the `IN` predicate:

```
SELECT data FROM sheet1 WHERE data IN(1, 2);
```